# Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Unable to import module 'lambda_function'

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sam

I have a lambda function that is deployed in cloudFormation via Codepipeline.

My folder structure is as shown below:

```
LambdaCode/
    lambda_function.py
samTemplate.yml
buildspec.yml
```

lambda_function.py

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = "Hello from lambda"
    return {"statusCode": 200, "body": json.dumps(response)}
```

samTemplate is as follows,

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: CD Demo Lambda
Resources:
  CDDemoLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: s3://<bkt-name>/LambdaCode.zip
      Description: 'Lambda function for CD Demo'
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        getAZsAPI:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /getpage
            Method: get
      Environment:
        Variables:
          REGION: <region>
```

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file samTemplate.yaml --s3-bucket artifact-store-s3 --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - samTemplate.yaml
    - outputSamTemplate.yaml
```

In code pipeline deployment stage I was getting an error when I give CodeUri as ./LambdaCode, hence I uploaded the LambdaCode as zip in a s3 bucket and gave the s3 URI as Codeuri. The pipeline ran successfully after that, but in the API gateway when I try to access the deployed URL I am getting the error in cloudwatch:

```
Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Unable to import module 'lambda_function'.
```

The deployment is not able to call the lambda_function. What could possibly be the reason?
Do I need to modify the lambda handler since I am using s3 URI?

Comment: What is inside the LambdaCode.zip? Is there a python folder at the top level?

Comment: the LambdaCode.zip is the lambda function folder

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of your zip, The main error is can't find the file or the handler.

I recommand you to package your lambda with the command SAM.

*Example :*

```
sam package --region eu-west-1 --template-file .sam-template.yml --s3-bucket artifact-bucket --output-template-file packaged.yml
```

and in your sam template you put the location of the code locally :

```
LoginFunction:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
Properties:
  FunctionName: 'usr-api-login-function'
  CodeUri: ./dist/user-login-function
  Policies:
    - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
        TableName: !Ref TableName
  Events:
    SearchPost:
      Type: Api
      Properties:
        RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
        Path: /user/login
        Method: POST
```

After that you can deploy it

```
sam deploy --region eu-west-1 --template-file packaged.yml --stack-name name-stack --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Comment: Initially I was using the location of the code as ./LambdaCode in code uri but in the deployment stage of the codepipeline we need to mention a cloud formation stack name. While creating the stack name if I give codeUri as ./LambdaCode it will raise error since  we are uploading only the sam file to create the stack name. that's why I uploaded the lambda folder in s3 and gave the url

Comment: The command "sam package",  package the code uri of the lambda and put it in s3 and generate a new file packaged.yml .  After that in your cloudformation you mention this file packaged.yml

Comment: The sam package command needs to be written in the buildspec file? Right now in my build spec I am using the following command :   aws cloudformation package --template-file samTemplate.yaml --s3-bucket artifact-store-s3 --output-template-file outputSamTemplate.yaml

Comment: yes, in your  buildspec and in your cloudformation command or operation you use the output file outputSamTemplate.yaml

Comment: yes that's already done and the pipeline has finished successfully. I'm getting this error on execution only